# Java Reflect and generic : not casting the class instance appropriately

Tags: java, generics, reflection

**I have an interface "Transformer"**

```
public interface Transformer <T1,T2,T3> 
{
    public T3 transform(T1 arg1, T2 arg2  ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException,Exception ;
}
```

**And there are 3 classes say A,B,C that implemented Transformer interface.**

Say, something like **a list of records need to go through the "transform" function of the classes A or B or C in a order described in the database**.Hence I had to use Reflect. I  created the instances of the classes before going through the list of the records in the way similar as this:

```
private void initiateTransFormerClazzes( List<String> classNames )
{
    clazzes = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();;

    for ( String className : classNames )
    {
        Class<?> clazz = null;
        try
        {
            clazz = Class.forName( className);
            Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor( arg1.class, arg2.class);
            Object handleInstance = ctor.newInstance( new Object[] { arg3, arg4 } );
            clazzes.put( clazz,handleInstance );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I have to initialize and store the instances of these classes in the beginning or prior to the going through the list of the records as each of these class's initialization is a long process.

Now, for pulling up the instance of each "Transformer" type class (A or B or C) , I have a method:

```
public <T> T getTransformerInstance(Class<T> clazz)
{
    return clazz.cast(clazzes.get(clazz));
}
```

**Now, I am trying a number of transformations on each of the records in the following way:**

```
for ( Record rec : Records)
{
    for (String className : classNames)
    {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName( className );
        rec = getTransformerInstance(clazz).transform( somearg1,rec);

    }
}
```

Looks like type casting is not done properly and **I am not seeing the "transform" method available on "getTransformerInstance(clazz)"**.

What am I missing?

Comment: Read up on wildcards, `?` and on generic bounds for type parameters.

Comment: Please also see this topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Out of your description it seems that you don't need Generics but a common interface for your classes A,B and C.

Comment: You won't be able to use generics here. Since you are getting the classes during execution (`forName`), you don't ever know at compilation what `T` is when you try to get the transformer. They don't really help you either. I agree with @dognose that you should be approaching this with polymorphism instead.